# Crystal reports in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i am doing practice in crystal reports in asp.net web application. I am finding two problems, first one is each time i run my app crystal reports ask for password to login the database and also do not update the dynamic fields. the second one is i want to open crystal report on click of button whenever i click on button object of crystal report creates and then it calls its page_load(this,null) in which i am giving parameter this and null but the page is not going to be open.

please help me and sorry for poor english

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. May be help to you...

Here's [a link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Dynamic_Crystal_Report.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

First You can try using datasets for avoiding logon credentials to be provided everytime crystal report is to be viewed. If you are using dataset make sure your dataset is preserved between each postback by storing the "session" dataset.

Second pass logon credentials programatically for the database being used. Passing logon credentials is explained in lot of forums.

Third, if you are using Submit button for viewing the report, make sure you effect a full postback on submit button click. You will find that all pages in the report will work perfectly fine.

Note: Use Trigger with Update Panel to Effect the Full Post Back (The Control ID of the trigger should be the ID of the button).